# Eclipse Juno 4.4.2 Error: Don't automatically create MainActiviy and activity_main layout when I create a new Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I create a new Android project. Activity Name, Layout Name is default (MainActivity and activity_main). But when a new project is created, missing MainActivity class and activity_main layout?
[image: Error image:]

Please help me! Thanks for reading!

Comment: Did you check them when you were creating your Project?
Anyway you can create them manually, Right click on your package in src folder>New>Class
And in layout right click>New>Other>XML file

Comment: I tried. But now, I can't create a new android activity and layout :(